# How to write argument parser such that it will give another parser when particular argument given

Tags: python-3.x

I have to print parser when choosing help for action and if action is test , then it should print all other event parser.

```
./dd.py -h 

./dd.py -a test -h
```

Here is main code:

```
def create_parser() -> argparse.ArgumentParser:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Manage event.”,
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-a",
        "--action",
        choices=[“test2”, “test”, “test”],
        help=“testing”,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "-s",
        "--service",
        help="Name of it",
    )

    return parser


def create_event_parser() -> argparse.ArgumentParser:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
        description="Manage events.",
        formatter_class=argparse.RawTextHelpFormatter,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--title",
        choices=[“c1”, “c2”],
        default=“c2”,
        help="Title of the event",
        required=False,
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--text",
        default="service is “here,
        help="Text content of the event",
    )
    return parser


def main() -> None:
    # Create a parser for the general arguments
    general_parser = create_parser()
    args, unknown_args = general_parser.parse_known_args()

    if args.action == “test”:
        # If the action is “test”, create and use the event-specific parser
        event_parser = create_event_parser()
        event_args = event_parser.parse_args()
        
        #event_parser.print_help()
        #return

    validated_args = ArgsModel(action=args.action, service_name=args.service_name)

     if args.action == “test”:
      # Call schedule_event method with provided parameters
         manager.schedule_event(
             title=event_args.title,
             text=event_args.text,
         )
     fi
```

Issue is, if I run command with argument `-a test` , its not printing event parser argument, if I print it here

```
    if args.action == “test”:
        # If the action is “test”, create and use the event-specific parser
        event_parser = create_event_parser()
        event_parser.print_help()
        return
```

Its printing parser but then how to assign **event_args** variable value.

```
         manager.schedule_event(
             title=event_args.title,
             text=event_args.text,
         )
```